# Data doesn`t enter properly in .dat file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

 using namespace std;

class Motherboards
{
char name[50];
char chip[50];
float price;

 public:
    void getdata()
   {
    cout << "Enter name :\n";
    cin.getline(name, 50);
    cout << "Chip :\n";
    cin.getline(chip, 50);
    cout << "Price:\n";
    cin >> price;
}
void putdata()
{
    cout << name << endl;
    cout << chip << endl;
    cout << price << endl;
}

}M;


int main()
{
long pos;
fstream input("Motherboard.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
M.getdata();
pos=input.tellg();
input.seekg(pos);
input.write((char*)&M,sizeof(M));
M.putdata();
return 0;
}
```

I can`t enter the data properly to the Motherboard.dat or the     Motherboard.txt. I have included pictures of when i run the program with one more edit to the above code and the output is not as expected. I am a beginner 
so please explain in detail on how to correct it.

Text:

```
Asus                                              X99                                                @GAsus                                              Z97                                                @œFÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ
```

[1st Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc4fM.png)

[2nd Run after edit which i actually want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNvXF.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Instead copy-paste the text, as text, into the body of your question.

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to make sure [the reading position is at the beginning](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) of the file before reading. You should probably also check that the writing and reading went okay.

Comment: That actually worked but now the problem is when i enter a new set of data the read function shows me the values of the data of the 1st set

Comment: Then *go back* `sizeof(M)` bytes?

Comment: you mean input.seekg(sizeof(M)); ?

Comment: Not quite. Please follow the link I provided to a `seekg` reference. You need to seek `-sizeof(M)` from the *current* position, if you want to read back the data you just wrote. Test! Experiment!

Comment: Thank you i got it . Now if say i want to modify a particular set how do i access any particular set ( to actually get the data altogether ) and modify the things that i want